# How to overwrite css style

Tags: html, css

In my css style I have this line of code:

```
.flex-control-thumbs li {
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
}
```

for my pages. Now, some of my pages don't need this line

```
width: 25%;
float: left;
```

It is possible to overwrite it in internal css of the page, which will cause the original behaviour to be ignored?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Using `!important` is not recommended but in this situation I think you should -

Write this in your internal CSS -

```
.flex-control-thumbs li {
  width: auto !important;
  float: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Why is !important not recommended?

Comment: @BenjaminBehar because it makes debugging more difficult by breaking the natural cascading in your stylesheets. When two conflicting declarations with the !important rule are applied to the same element, the declaration with greater specificity will be applied.

Comment: It isn't that `!important` isn't recommended; it's part of the spec and is fine to use. The important thing is to use it sparingly, only when needed. It's the sledgehammer of CSS.

Answer (score 11):

instead of overwriting, create it as different css and call it in your element as other css(multiple css). 
Something like:

```
.flex-control-thumbs li 
{ margin: 0; }
```

---

Internal CSS:

```
.additional li
{width: 25%; float: left;}
```

---

```
<ul class="flex-control-thumbs additional"> </ul> /* assuming parent is ul */
```

Answer (score 7):

## Increase your [CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Example:

```
.parent-class .flex-control-thumbs li {
  width: auto;
  float: none;
}
```

Demo:

```css
.sample-class {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: red;
}

.inner-page .sample-class {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="sample-class"></div>
</div>

<div class="inner-page">
  <div class="sample-class"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can create one more class naming

```
.flex-control-thumbs-without-width li {
width: auto;
float: initial; or none
}
```

Add this class whenever you need to override like below,

```
<li class="flex-control-thumbs flex-control-thumbs-without-width"> </li>
```

And do remove whenever you don't need for other `<li>`

Answer (score 3):

Just add

```
.flex-control-thumbs li {
width: auto; 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add your styles in the required page after the external style sheet so they'll cascade and overwrite the first set of rules.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="allpages.css">
<style>
.flex-control-thumbs li {
  width: auto;
  float: none;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can indeed. There are three ways of achieving this that I can think of.

1. Add inline styles to the elements.
2. create and append a new <style> element, and add the text to override this
   style to it.
3. Modify the css rule itself.

Notes:

1. is somewhat messy and adds to the parsing the browser needs to do to
   render.
2. perhaps my favourite method
3. Not cross-browser, some browsers like it done one way, others a different
   way, while the remainder just baulk at the idea.