# Remove .ui-state-default

Tags: html, css

I could able to remove `.ui-state-default` in the inspector panel, but I need to know how could I able to do it in the html or css

[image]

Comment: Override the styles with your own.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to overwrite css style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13117126/how-to-overwrite-css-style) Tough it is possible to use `!important` it is not recommended. Just voting to close as it seems there was no real effort into searching for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Simply set those styles to default at the end of your CSS file.

```
.ui-state-default {
  border: none;
  background-color: initial;
  color: initial;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
.ui-state-default
{
   border:unset;
   background:unset;
   color:unset;
}
```

Comment: `unset` is not supported enough to be used in production. [88.51%](https://caniuse.com/#search=unset)