# CSS doesnt overwrite style

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, stylesheet

I have 2 stylesheet files, style.css, and index.css which are loading respectively

1-style.css
2-index.css

in my style.css I have code like this

```
#mainNav nav > a:hover span:before {
    background-color: transparent !important;
}

#mainNav nav a.darkBlue span:before {
        background-color: #17729a;
}
```

now in my index.css

when I write

```
#mainNav .darkBlue span:before {
background-color: transparent;
}
```

It doesnt work and I should write !important at the end to make it work

but when I write selectors order in a different way like the way I used in my style.css it works without !important

like this

```
#mainNav nav a.darkBlue span:before {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

Why?

Comment: Because you use !important in your first css tag

Comment: no, thats not the reason, the important thing is about :hover

Comment: `#mainNav nav a.darkBlue span:before {` is more specific than `#mainNav .darkBlue span:before {` and will take precedence.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to overwrite css style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13117126/how-to-overwrite-css-style)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your declarations are being applied based on how *specific* they are.

Per [MDN - Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity):

> Specificity is the means by which browsers decide which CSS property values are the most relevant to an element and, therefore, will be applied.
>
> Specificity is a weight that is applied to a given CSS declaration, determined by the number of each selector type in the matching selector.

The link above also goes into the factors that determine specificity:

> The following list of selector types increases by specificity:
>
> 1. Type selectors (e.g., `h1`) and pseudo-elements (e.g., `::before`).
> 2. Class selectors (e.g., `.example`), attributes selectors (e.g., `[type="radio"]`) and pseudo-classes (e.g., `:hover`).
> 3. ID selectors (e.g., `#example`).
>
> Universal selector (`*`), combinators (`+`, `>`, `~`, `' '`) and negation pseudo-class (`:not()`) have no effect on specificity. (The selectors declared inside `:not()` do, however.)

---

CSS chooses which rules to apply based on a few conditions. Given rules applying to the same element, they are regarded in the following order:

#### 1. `!important`

```css
span { color: red; }               /* base */
#mySpan { color: blue; }           /* specific  */
span { color: green !important; }  /* important */
```

```html
<span id="mySpan" style="color: purple;">Example</span>
```

#### 2. Inline styles

```css
span { color: red; }               /* base */
#mySpan { color: blue; }           /* specific  */
```

```html
<span id="mySpan" style="color: purple;">Example</span>
```

#### 3. Specificity

```css
span { color: red; }               /* base */
#mySpan { color: blue; }           /* specific  */
```

```html
<span id="mySpan">Example</span>
```

#### 4. Last declared

```css
span { color: red; }               /* base */
span { color: yellow; }            /* last applied */
```

```html
<span>Example</span>
```

---

It's generally best to avoid using `!important` wherever possible. If you throw them around carelessly, there may come a time when you *actually* need to override one, but you've already used your highest order of precedence.

Answer (score 3):

CSS has a hierarchy. If you you wanna overwrite some styles you have to use the same selectors or some more specific.

Example:

```
a.selector { color: blue }
.selector { color: red }
```

The color will not be changed.

But

```
.selector { color: blue }
a.selector { color: red }
```

will change the color to red, because the combination of TAG and class selector you are more specific.

Comment: And in addition, here's the [MDN on CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

Answer (score 2):

You have something called CSS specificity:

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_specificity.asp

A really great read on what comes first and the order of specificity: check https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/
Be aware, it's a loooong article. Most people don't even have the slightest idea of how far this goes.

> Simply put: If two CSS selectors apply to the same element, the one
>   with higher specificity wins.

That's why I follow the [BEM](http://getbem.com/introduction/) methodology, this prevents these kinds of hassles.