# Angular - Evaluation order of css classes

Tags: css, angular

I'm migrating my applications to Angular 16 and Material and replacing flex-layout that is not supported anymore.

I'm also refactoring css using scss but Im again confronting with the problem of class style evaluations order and I dont wuant to use "important" anymore.

Unfortunally, Angular still put its style AFTER my styles.

In my angular.json, I have this sequence:

```
[
 "./node_modules/@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.min.css",
 "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css",
 "src/styles.scss",
 "src/darkmode.scss"
]
```

For Example, I have a material-icon-button.

```
<button mat-icon-button class="add-button">
 ...
</button>
```

At runtime, Angular translate it with:

```
<button _ngcontent-ng-c4190991567="" mat-icon-button="" class="add-button mdc-icon-button mat-mdc-icon-button mat-unthemed mat-mdc-button-base"><span class="mat-mdc-button-persistent-ripple mdc-icon-button__ripple"></span>
 ...
</button>
```

Any style I put in add-button classes, is overrided by all the mdc* classes that are evaluated after as you can see from image.

[image]

I know ::ng-deep etc... are deprecated.

So how can I make my classes wins againts realtime styles?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS doesnt overwrite style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53413804/css-doesnt-overwrite-style)