# React, Overwrite/Remove CSS, Semantic UI

Tags: css, reactjs, semantic-ui

I have a React component using Semantic-UI.  I am trying to remove the width attribute.
The inspector shows the element's CSS as below:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px)
.ui.container {
    width: 1127px;
    margin-left: auto!important;
    margin-right: auto!important;
}
```

I'd like to somehow remove the width.  How can this be done?  Do I have to use styled-components? If so, I'm a little confused as to how...
Thanks!

Comment: how do you currently handle custom style for your components? if you are unsure, you can just use a custom stylesheet and increase [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I am using a css file and importing into the component.  I am aware of specificity but I guess I dont have a grasp on it yet.  I am running into trouble figuring where to add the ampersands `&&` and if adding the styled-components module is necessary to do so.

Comment: you can use that CSS file and overwrite the styles there: `.parent-class-name .ui.container { width: auto; }` you don't need styled-components

Comment: you're welcome - have a look at my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64084064/8680805 for more insight