# Overwrite CSS in a Drupal backoffice

Tags: html, css

I need to overwrite some CSS in a Drupal back office (I can't change the CSS) and I tried to follow the instructions of this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13117126/how-to-overwrite-css-style).

So I made the following code :

**EDIT**

```
<style type="text/css">.maclasse div {
background: #ffffff;
overflow:auto;
width:auto;
}
.maclasse2 tbody tr td {
    text-align: left;
}
</style>
```

And then, in the HTML I used my side classes :

```
<div class="maclasse maclasse2">
<table class="maclasse2">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <pre style="margin: 0; line-height: 125%">
                ....
```

But it is not working ; the inspection of the page shows that :
[image: override denied]

In td, the text-align is still centered and we can see the override is denied. What do I need to add to my code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if just text in html like this code

```
<td class= "montd">
...
<span>text</span>
...
</td>
```

in css selected like this

```
.montd span {
     text-align: left;
    }
```

Comment: Ok, I changed accordingly to your suggestion : now we can see in the picture that the override is denied (cf. my edits)

Comment: have you tried adding !important in css 
.montd span {
     text-align: left !important;
    }

Comment: yes now it is working. Thank you !

Comment: have a nice day